# iperf3 limiting bandwidth fails

Tags: networking, bandwidth, iperf

I want to use iperf3 to test some QoS settings of a router. Therefore I want to simulate a lone-lasting but low bandwidth connection.*

I tried the following:

```
$ iperf3 -c MYSERVER -b 100K
Connecting to host MYSERVER, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.1.45 port 39042 connected to MYSERVER port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  16.0 KBytes   131 Kbits/sec    0   18.7 KBytes
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  37.4 KBytes   306 Kbits/sec    0   30.7 KBytes
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0   30.7 KBytes
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0   30.7 KBytes
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  64.1 KBytes   525 Kbits/sec    0   33.4 KBytes
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0   33.4 KBytes
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0   33.4 KBytes
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0   33.4 KBytes
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0   33.4 KBytes
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  74.8 KBytes   613 Kbits/sec    0   33.4 KBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   192 KBytes   158 Kbits/sec    0             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   176 KBytes   144 Kbits/sec                  receiver
```

So, somehow the bandwidth limit is not applied.

It gets worse if I try localhost

```
$ iperf3 -c localhost -b 100K
Connecting to host localhost, port 5201
[  4] local 127.0.0.1 port 52222 connected to 127.0.0.1 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   128 KBytes  1.05 Mbits/sec    0    639 KBytes
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0    639 KBytes
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0    639 KBytes
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0    639 KBytes
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0    639 KBytes
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0    639 KBytes
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0    639 KBytes
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0    639 KBytes
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0    639 KBytes
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec    0    639 KBytes
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   128 KBytes   105 Kbits/sec    0             sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   128 KBytes   105 Kbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

Does anyone have an idea what I do wrong?

I tried iperf3 versions 3.0.7 and 3.0.12

*In the end I want to ensure that some low-bandwidth connections are preferred over anything else in the network.